# Filter objects via streams

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of objects like below

```
public class Price{

    private long id;

    private String productid;

    private long sequence;

    private BigDecimal price;
    
}
```

i will have list of objects like below

```
Price1 -> {1, "p1", 1, 1.0}
Price2 -> {2, "p1", 2, 2.0}
Price3 -> {3, "p1", 3, 3.0}
Price4 -> {4, "p2", 1, 1.0}
```

each product id can have multiple entries of prices(ordered by sequence).
The latest price comes with latest sequence.
in the above data, product p1 price is 3, p2's price is 1.

I need to filter the above list of java objects to get only 2 entries(id 3 and 4).
the output should come with below list

```
Price3 -> {3, "p1", 3, 3.0}
Price4 -> {4, "p2", 1, 1.0}
```

Any help with Java8 streams?

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: Assignment for study or assessment :) Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to use `groupingBy` rather than `filter` to get desired output. Please refer below example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Price> data = Arrays.asList(
                new Price(1, "p1", 1, new BigDecimal(1.0)),
                new Price(2, "p1", 2, new BigDecimal(2.0)),
                new Price(3, "p1", 3, new BigDecimal(3.0)),
                new Price(4, "p2", 1, new BigDecimal(1.0)));

        Map<String, Object> result = data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Price::getProductid,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.reducing((Price p1, Price p2) -> p1.getSequence() > p2.getSequence() ? p1 : p2),
                        Optional::get)));

        System.out.println(result.values());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Price(id=3, productid=p1, sequence=3, price=3), Price(id=4, productid=p2, sequence=1, price=1)]
```

`Price` class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Price {
    private long id;
    private String productid;
    private long sequence;
    private BigDecimal price;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Collectors.groupingBy` to group the prices per product and then `Collectors.maxBy` to get the latest price from the list. The result is a map with latest price per products.

```java
Map<String, Price> lastPricePerProduct = data.stream().collect(
Collectors.groupingBy(Price::getProductid, Collectors.collectingAndThen(                
Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Price::getSequence)), Optional::get));
```

More elegant solution with `Collectors.toMap` and `BinaryOperator.maxBy`:

```java
Map<String, Price> lastPricePerProduct = data.stream().collect(
Collectors.toMap(Price::getProductid,Function.identity(),
    BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Price::getSequence))));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```java
prices.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Price::getProductid)).entrySet().forEach(e -> e.getValue().stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Price::getSequence)).get());
```

***NOTE:*** I have not tested above code so it may have some incorrect semantics.

***Explanation:***

1. Collect respective price objects in map according to product. `Collectors.groupingBy(Price::getProductid)`
2. Stream through each keys' list of prices. `entrySet().forEach()`
3. Find max sequence for each key and return object. `max(Comparator.comparing(Price::getSequence)).get()`

Let me know if you require any further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

As [java.util.stream.Stream#predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) accepts "a non-interfering, stateless predicate",
I think you should use a `Collection` for that.

I would use [java.util.stream.Stream#collect](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) with a `Collector`.
[java.util.stream.Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) makes it convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 List<Price> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Price p1 = new Price(1,"p1",1,new BigDecimal(1.0));
    Price p2 = new Price(2,"p1",2,new BigDecimal(2.0));
    Price p3 = new Price(3,"p1",3,new BigDecimal(3.0));
    Price p4 = new Price(4,"p3",1,new BigDecimal(1.0));
    list.add(p1);
    list.add(p2);
    list.add(p3);
    list.add(p4);
    List<Price> priceList = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Price::getSequence).reversed())
            .filter(distinctByKey(Price::getProductid))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.print(priceList);

public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, Object> keyExtractor)
{
    Map<Object, Boolean> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return t -> map.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
}
```

Output: `[Price{id=3, productid='p1', sequence=3, price=3}, Price{id=4, productid='p3', sequence=1, price=1}]`